# Search text/word in mysql but not remembered the tables and columns

Tags: mysql

There is a text/words in my source code that I want to change, I just forgot where I putted the words, I've been looking all my source codes but is not anywhere there.

I just guessed I put the text/words in the database, but when I looked at my database, God...there are 70 tables. It's just a developed site years by years.

And I just don't know how to find the words on all that tables. I knew the standard queries search in MySQL is:

```
Select * from [tables_name] Where [Column_name] LIKE %.....%
```

But I really don't remembered the tables or the columns. I need help for the queries.

Comment: dump all the tables. use grep or some other text search to find your value, and the table its in